# is there TRUNCATE in Access?

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in an Access database with an autonumber field.

When I delete all the records from the table, the autonumber remembers the last number.

Does Access have something similar to SQL Server's `TRUNCATE TABLE MyTbl`?

If not, how to start with 1 after I delete the table's records?

Comment: You don't mean "after I delete the table" -- you mean "after I delete all the records in the table". If you deleted the actual table, you would definitely get a new autonumber value.

Answer (score 26):

Access SQL does not have anything like `TRUNCATE TABLE`.

You can use an ADO connection to execute a DDL statement which resets the autonumber field's *"seed"* value. So you could do this with VBA code, and not have to use compact & repair to reset the autonumber.

This example code first deletes all rows from my *tblFoo* table, and then resets the seed value for the *id* autonumber field.

```vb
Dim strSql As String
strSql = "DELETE FROM tblFoo;"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
strSql = "ALTER TABLE tblFoo ALTER COLUMN id COUNTER (1, 1);"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
```

Answer (score 7):

There's no truncate in MS Access as far as I know but you can resolve the auto-number issue remembering the last number after delete. There's a way in MS Access to start with 1 after deleting records with auto-number field. If you're using [ms-access-2007](/questions/tagged/ms-access-2007) you can find the **Compact and Repair Database** feature by selecting Manage, located under the Office Button. You can also have your database compact and repair itself every time it is closed, by activating the **Compact on Close** option. If you would like to set this option, you can find it in the **Access Options** for the Current Database.

[image]

Comment: How is this related to truncate functionality?

Answer (score 5):

Or without compact and repair:

Empty your table:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable
```

Alter autoincrementfield (like 'ID') to Integer:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER Column ID INT;
```

Alter the field back to AUTOINCREMENT:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ALTER Column ID AUTOINCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 3):

In MS_Access Database, "Truncate is not supported". So we can delete the all records first by "Delete" query.

After delete the records, we can alter the "ID" column starts from 1 by using "Alter" query.

Query:

```
  "Delete * from (Your Table Name); 
  Alter Table (Your Table Name) Alter Column (Your Column Id) Counter(1,1);"
```

Using this two queries in single execution we can delete all records and reset the column id starts from 1.

Comment: There is no additional information whatsoever in this answer compared to [the answer by HansUp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7237441/3820271). What was the point of posting this answer?

Comment: I am not seeing the answer of HansUp. Because there is no tick mark on any answer. So only add my answer in my point of few.

Answer (score 2):

took 1 second to find the solution at:

http://www.webmasterworld.com/databases_sql_mysql/3227574.htm

> The Compact and Repair process will reset all empty table
>   auto-increment counters to zero. So, delete all the records then:
>
> Tools -> Database Utilities -> Compact and Repair Database

Comment: As of office 365, mine doesn't anymore. :(

Answer (score 2):

There is another way that doesn't require altering the table or compacting and repairing. It will work better for you if you have a distributed database.  As of 2000, Access will accept an insert value into an autonumber field and start incrementing there.  Do it in a query or in code like this.

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "DELETE FROM Mytbl"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "INSERT INTO Mytbl(ID) VALUES(0)"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "DELETE FROM Mytbl"
```

Note: Put adExecuteNoRecords after the execute command for better performance.  e.g. CurrentProject.Connection.Execute sql, , adExecuteNoRecords

Answer (score 1):

Delete all the records and then compact the database.

Answer (score 1):

I also the same problem before, what I did was I go back to the table in modify mode. Then I deleted the field name with autonumber and I inserted again with the same name. The result of the autonumber when I run in view mode was back to the number 1 the first Entry.

Comment: Worked for me, I guess the simplest and shortest route is to delete and recreate the autonumber field.

Answer (score 0):

Or without Compact and Repair when using VBA:
Say your table is 'MyTable'. Make a copy of that table WITHOUT data and save it for example as 'MyTable_Template'.
When you want to Truncate the table just 'DROP' the table en copy 'MyTable_Template' to 'MyTable'. Now the autoincrementfield of your 'new' table 'MyTable' will start at 1 again.